# Zip Files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, zip

I am creating a game currently and I want users to be able to upload their save games to my site for them to retrieve later, like if they log into another computer or accidentally delete their save from their computer. I want the file to be linked to the specific user that uploaded it, which is easy to do. I have a MySQL database set up that stores the usernames and passwords. The way I think I am going to link the file to the user is to upload the file with its name the same as the username. My problem is I don't want the files to be able to be accessed without being the owner of the file and I don't want them all sitting on my web server taking up more room than is needed. I think a good solution is to zip them up together. What would the easiest way to do that is and be able to retrieve it without unzipping every single file in it to get the one save file. Is it possible to take just one file out of it? I am reading up on the zip functions, http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php. Also, is there a better/easier way of setting each file to a specific "owner"? Thanks!

Edit: I want to both zip and unzip the file(s).

Comment: You want to zip them, but you don't want to unzip them?

Comment: Sorry, I want to do both zip and unzip. I must not have said that sorry. I will add to first post!

Comment: I think you need to rethink your strategy here.

Comment: What would you suggest doing instead?

Comment: What type of files should be uploaded?

Comment: Not zipping the files. Getting a bigger hard drive ans storing everything in it's normal state.

Comment: Correct you wouldn't zip all the files, that's just lost server performance.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you! I am using a free host right now. They may not be happy if I do a lot of CPU intensive functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to save all users files into the same big one? I don't think it's a good idea... Your server will spend a lot of time to find the only small file that needs to be unzipped, and it's the same for insertion.

Instead, simply zip each files individually. YOu'll still save some space, but without eating 100% of the resources of your server.

To link users & files, you just needs 2 tables, users and savegames. It's better to do the link between those tables using user_id, MySQL is faster on integers than varchar.

Here are some examples from php.net http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: Oh OK. I can't seem to figure out the Zip functions though. Could you give me a simple example of zipping and unzipping? Sometimes php.net doesn't give me enough info.

Comment: That zipping is not easy, and it's really not a good idea for what you want to. If you need it for something else you could just search the web for that there has to be a tutorial.

Comment: What would you suggest over my original idea? The files I would be uploading would be very small. Just a few kilobytes, maybe up to a megabyte or two so the zipping is not really necessary now that I think about it. What I am more worried about is if there gets to be a lot of files on the server.

Comment: Just let the user upload their file onto the server. I don't know how large these savegames are, but you could also just save these files as 'username.*savegameextension*'. Then you wouldn't need the second table in your database, if the script only lets the user download his file. Or should the users be able to upload more than one file? Than it would be besser with a table.

Comment: You should make a file size and number of files limit. E.g. Every user can upload 5 files with max. 1 mb...

Comment: I've edited my answer with some comprehensive examples (from php.net :p ). Whatever you do, you will still have a lot of files in your server. Just put them all in the same place, and it should be OK... If you want to be clean, then you can create 1 folder by user, but I'm not sure it's necessary.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! Their save games "should" only get up to maybe 2 Mb. They should average around a couple of kilobytes though so the size is little problem. I figured their save game would just be their username then the extension like you suggested. Thank you as well haltabrush!